# changing cell bgcolor on mouseover

Tags: c#, asp.net, row, html-table

I have a listview that highlights a row when you mouseover it with the code below:

for TR:

```
<tr class="trAlt" onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="outalt(this)">

<script>
    function over(o) {
        if ('trClicked' != o.className)
            o.className = 'trOver';
    function outalt(o) {
        if ('trClicked' != o.className)
            o.className = 'trAlt';
   function clicked(o) {
        o.className = ('trClicked' == o.className) ? 'tr' : 'trClicked';
</script>
```

Now for one particular cell I need to set bgcolor based on the value it contains and I do it like so:

```
<td nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor='<%#Get_BGColor(Eval("Efficiency"),Eval("AvgAdjEfficiency"))%>'>
   <asp:Label ID="EfficiencyLabel" runat="server" 
       Text='<%# Eval("Efficiency") %>' />
</td>
```

Style tag:

```
<style>
       /* ItemTemplate TR background colour */
        .tr 
        {
            background-color:#222;
        } 
        /* AlternatingItemTemplate TR background colour */
        .trAlt
        {
            background-color:#595959;
        }
        /* When mouse is over TR background colour */
        .trOver 
        {
            background-color:#898989;
        } 
        /* When mouse click on TR background colour */
        .trClicked 
        {
            background-color:Red;
        } 
    </style>
```

The problem is that the cell above overwrites the bgcolor of that row when you mouseover (function over() above).

How can I make it so that when you mouseover it changes that cells bgcolor to the highlight color too, and then set it back (function outalt() above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css

```
.trAlt:hover td{
   background: red;
}
```

Comment: that still does not highlight the cell which i manually set the bgcolor for

Comment: remove the bgcolor you setted manually and add css like   .trAlt{ background: your-color; } .trAlt:hover{
   background: red;
}

Comment: But i need that cells bg color to be different. when not hovering over. So if all the row's normal (unhighlighted) bgcolor is White the one cells should be green. Then when hovering the row, all cells should be red.

Comment: Another way but not sure how to do it, would be to check the value of the cell and set its class to one that sets bgcolor to one green/orange/red. But at the moment I am checking the value on the code behind page

Comment: I have it working as per the fiddle, but I need one cell to stay green when all other cells are red (when not hovering over), when hovering over all should be red

Comment: Check updated fiddle to see how i have it currently. http://jsfiddle.net/ZvcXy/1/ so I want the red cell to turn green when hovered over, and stay red otherwise

Answer (score 2):

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
<Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%# Eval("ItemID") %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="highlightBox">
              <%# Eval("Title") %>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

```
.highlightBox
{

}

.highlightBox:hover
{
  background-color: Yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, If you want your bg to return to how it is originally then

in your tr tag

```
class="trAlt" onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="outalt(this)"
```

Once you have all of that done add the styles that the guy all the way at the top gave you and put that piece of good work into the head tag... then you should see that when you hover over any of the cells in that row it should highlight all the cells in that row. If that did not work then Look through your code... and find the problem.

Also I haven't used the script tag or the asp tag cause they were just some extra stuff that was bugging out the cells like... one of the cells would turn green and stay that way unless you hover over it then it would go back to staying green.

Answer (score -1):

what is definition of trOver and trAlt? are you setting background-color there?

Comment: :(  why down vote? is it a sin to ask for more detail? see the above comment of  user1468537...he updated the question, which helped him to get the answer.